# Find the value of $E=\sum_{k=1}^4 \big(\cos\frac{k \pi}{9}\big)^4.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

> Find the value of 
>   $$E=\sum_{k=1}^4 \big(\cos\frac{k \pi}{9}\big)^4.$$

Source: list of problems related to the preparation for math contests. No answer provided.

**My attempt:** I looked into
$$\sum_{k=1}^4 z^{k4}$$
for $z=cis(\pi/9)$, but this doesn't appear to be useful.

Hints and full answers are appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Math contest.. My intuition is that it should be enough with expanding double angle formulas / Euler complex exponential representation a couple of times and to look for cancelling terms, using trig identity and maybe derive the cos/sin value for one particular term that remains..

Comment: Let $z=e^{\pi i/9}$. Write $2\cos(k\pi/9)=z^k+z^{-k}$. Expand the fourth powers using the binomial formula. Clear negative powers of $z$ using $z^{18}=1$. Use the relation $$1+z^2+z^4+\cdots+z^{16}=0$$ where the left hand side is a geometric sum equal to $(1-z^{18})/(1-z^2)$. Unless I made a mistake that's all you need to do. The answer is a rational number with double digit numerator/denominator.

Comment: Yes, use Jyrkis approach instead, it seems more systematic. It is good to learn to be systematic, more useful later the more you relied on intuition in your youth.

Comment: I get $\frac{19}{16}$

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas I believe your result is correct.

Comment: Yes. I got the same answer @Aleksas did.